# Need Help in writing SQL Query with multiple one to many relationships

Tags: sql-server

I have 3 tables with this schema:

**Table1**

```
CREATE TABLE #tmpGroundPreferenceProfile
(
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](50) NULL
 )
INSERT #tmpGroundPreferenceProfile ([Id], [Name]) VALUES (1, N'Profile1') 
INSERT #tmpGroundPreferenceProfile ([Id], [Name]) VALUES (2, N'Profile2') 
INSERT #tmpGroundPreferenceProfile ([Id], [Name]) VALUES (3, N'Profile3')
```

**Table2**

```
CREATE TABLE #tmpGroundPreferenceLocations(
    [Id] [int]  NOT NULL,
    [GroundPreferenceProfileId] [int] NULL,
    [DistrictId] [int] NULL,
    [RanchId] [int] NULL,
    [FieldId] [int] NULL
)

INSERT #tmpGroundPreferenceLocations ([Id], [GroundPreferenceProfileId], [DistrictId], [RanchId], [FieldId]) VALUES (1, 1, 1, NULL, NULL)
INSERT #tmpGroundPreferenceLocations ([Id], [GroundPreferenceProfileId], [DistrictId], [RanchId], [FieldId]) VALUES (2, 1, 1, 1, NULL)
INSERT #tmpGroundPreferenceLocations ([Id], [GroundPreferenceProfileId], [DistrictId], [RanchId], [FieldId]) VALUES (3, 1, 1, 1, 1)
```

**Table3**

```
CREATE TABLE #tmpGroundPreferenceRatings(
    [Id] [int]  NOT NULL,
    [GroundPreferenceLocationId] [int] NULL,
    [Rating] [int] NULL,
    [Week] [int] NULL
)
INSERT #tmpGroundPreferenceRatings ([Id], [GroundPreferenceLocationId], [Rating], [Week]) VALUES (2, 1, 11, 1)
INSERT #tmpGroundPreferenceRatings ([Id], [GroundPreferenceLocationId], [Rating], [Week]) VALUES (3, 1, 12, 2)
INSERT #tmpGroundPreferenceRatings ([Id], [GroundPreferenceLocationId], [Rating], [Week]) VALUES (4, 1, 13, 3)
INSERT #tmpGroundPreferenceRatings ([Id], [GroundPreferenceLocationId], [Rating], [Week]) VALUES (5, 2, 21, 1)
INSERT #tmpGroundPreferenceRatings ([Id], [GroundPreferenceLocationId], [Rating], [Week]) VALUES (6, 2, 22, 2)
INSERT #tmpGroundPreferenceRatings ([Id], [GroundPreferenceLocationId], [Rating], [Week]) VALUES (7, 2, 23, 3)
INSERT #tmpGroundPreferenceRatings ([Id], [GroundPreferenceLocationId], [Rating], [Week]) VALUES (8, 3, 31, 1)
INSERT #tmpGroundPreferenceRatings ([Id], [GroundPreferenceLocationId], [Rating], [Week]) VALUES (9, 3, 32, 2)
INSERT #tmpGroundPreferenceRatings ([Id], [GroundPreferenceLocationId], [Rating], [Week]) VALUES (10, 3, 33, 3)
INSERT #tmpGroundPreferenceRatings ([Id], [GroundPreferenceLocationId], [Rating], [Week]) VALUES (11, 1, 14, 4)
INSERT #tmpGroundPreferenceRatings ([Id], [GroundPreferenceLocationId], [Rating], [Week]) VALUES (12, 1, 15, 5)
INSERT #tmpGroundPreferenceRatings ([Id], [GroundPreferenceLocationId], [Rating], [Week]) VALUES (13, 2, 24, 6)
INSERT #tmpGroundPreferenceRatings ([Id], [GroundPreferenceLocationId], [Rating], [Week]) VALUES (14, 2, 25, 7)
```

**Description**:

Against each profile there can be multiple locations and against each location there can be multiple ratings.

i.e.

1. there is one-to-many relation ship between tmpGroundPreferenceProfile and tmpGroundPreferenceLocations
2. there is one-to-many relation ship between tmpGroundPreferenceLocations and #tmpGroundPreferenceRatings

**Question**:

There can be multiple rating exists against a week. I want to get the rating in the following order,

First check for the District, Ranch and Field - If rating exists against this combination then get it else if rating doesn't exist then check for the District and Ranch combination, if rating exists against this combination then get it else if rating doesn't exist then check for the district location to get the rating.

**Note** :

There can be a multiple rating exists against the week 1, i.e. can exist for District and Ranch and can exist for District,Ranch and Field and so on...

I need to get the records week wise,

```
SELECT *
FROM #tmpGroundPreferenceProfile GPP
INNER JOIN #tmpGroundPreferenceLocations GPL    
ON GPL.GroundPreferenceProfileId = GPP.Id
INNER JOIN #tmpGroundPreferenceRatings GPR
ON GPR.GroundPreferenceLocationId = GPL.Id
WHERE GPP.Id = 1    
AND GPR.[Week] IN (1,3,4)
```

Any help from you guys is highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the desired result of the the query?

Comment: Here's a fiddle if anyone needs: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4808f/2/0

Comment: Not clear here. You want one record per week? One record per week per profile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have noted, your question isn't clear. I took a shot anyway, sometimes that can help clarify things.

```
SELECT *
FROM (

  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY GPR.Week
                        ORDER BY GPL.DistrictId,
                          GPL.RanchID DESC,
                          GPL.FieldID DESC
                          ) AS RN,
      GPP.ID,
      GPL.DistrictId,
      GPL.RanchID,
      GPL.FieldID,
      GPR.Rating,
      GPR.Week
    FROM tmpGroundPreferenceProfile GPP
    JOIN tmpGroundPreferenceLocations GPL
    ON GPL.GroundPreferenceProfileId = GPP.Id
    JOIN tmpGroundPreferenceRatings GPR
    ON GPR.GroundPreferenceLocationId = GPL.Id
    WHERE GPP.Id = 1
 ) X
WHERE X.RN = 1
ORDER BY X.Week, X.districtid
```

What this gives you is the first occurrence for each district and week. If there are multiple rows for the same district, ranch, field and week, the order is arbitrary, so you'll get an arbitrary row.

Is this close to what you are looking for?